# added additional fields value not displayed in customer module grid in magento

Tags: magento, grid, magento-1.7, custom-fields

I created a new module for listing customers in magento backend.

Everything will be fine, but here have some issues.

I created some additional fields to customer registratios.This fields value not displaying in gird now.

This is my `grid.php` code:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Test_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->setId('customerGrid');
       $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
       $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
       $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
   }
   protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('usertype')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
            'index'     => 'firstname'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
            'index'     => 'lastname'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('usertype', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('User Type'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'usertype'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
         return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
}
```

The firstname,lastname,email displayed correctly but the column for usertype not displaying nay value.

How can i do this?

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to add the new added columns to the grid with $this->addColumn()

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'lastname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'email'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('usertype', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('User Type'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'usertype'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));

    // Changed lines here
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    return $this;
    // end of changed lines

}
```

Comment: Ok, then change it back to `return parent::_prepareColumns();`.  See my edited answer above